# How much of C.S Peirce's categories is new to him?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind

One of the very early papers of Peirce deal with his [categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_(Peirce)).
How much of his categories are original to him?

I am particularly interested in the "firstness" which he characterizes as the quality of feeling and secondness the Reaction, resistance, (dyadic) relation.

Were there any earlier philosophical or scientific works that classified the first reaction that one may have about something as the feeling followed by vague thought that is (ideally) clarified over time into discrete facts or relations?

Comment: "Feeling followed by vague thought that is (ideally) clarified over time into discrete facts or relations" sounds like Hegel's unfolding of the Notion, and Hegel was, of course, Peirce's self-admitted inspiration, along with Kant and Aristotle. But this particular aspect is a side issue to the peculiar mix of proto-"qualia" with monadic relationality that Peirce pours into his Firstness. His entire categorical scheme is *sui generis*, even quaint.

Comment: @conifold can you expand on that?